# Convert varchar column to enum mysql

Tags: mysql

This may be a stupid question but I'm curious to hear opinions about converting my existing column named: country varchar(40) to enum and hard code the list of all countries, does making this change improve performance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

It should improve performance and reduce disk space usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you use any 3rd party report writing tools, you will lose the country names.

[EDIT] And, as countries come and go, you can add/remove them more easily to/from a database table rather than editing and recompiling the program.